# MAUI prompt for biometric/Pin authentication when leaving the app and then going back to it

Tags: .net, maui

I'm using the nuget package Plugin.Fingerprint in my MAUI app to enable the use of the device authentication. I have the code working on one of my forms. But now Im trying to apply it so when I resume the use of the app it will prompt for a security check (if enabled).

In my MauiProgram.cs I Have

```
builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(AppLifecycle => {
#if ANDROID
     AppLifecycle.AddAndroid(android => android
        .OnRestart((activity) =>
        
            LocalDeviceAuthPrompt()               
        ));
#endif
    });
```

and a private method

```
private static bool LocalDeviceAuthPrompt()
{
    var isAvailable = CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailableAsync(true).Result;

    if (isAvailable)
    {
        var request = new AuthenticationRequestConfiguration
        ("Login using biometrics", "Confirm login with your biometrics");
        request.AllowAlternativeAuthentication = true;
        var result = CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(request).Result;

        if (result.Authenticated)
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I know theres plenty wrong with it, for a start async is needed but the AppLifecycle implementation doesnt support it. It also doesnt work. the event fires but I never get a security prompt. Does anyone have any advice/recommendations

**UPDATE1**

So I removed the above code and added it to the app.xaml.cs file as follows

```
protected override async void OnResume()
    {
        var isAvailable = await CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailableAsync(true);

        if (isAvailable)
        {
            var request = new AuthenticationRequestConfiguration
            ("Login using biometrics", "Confirm login with your biometrics");
            request.AllowAlternativeAuthentication = true;
            var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(request);

            Console.Write(result);

        }
    }
```

I do get to decorate the method with async but it has the exact same issue. It doesn't go any further than line "CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(request)" . No error it just hangs

Comment: why don't you just use `OnResume`?

Comment: OnResume does get a little further, it does prompt for security but never gets passed that stage.

Comment: you need to use `async`.  `Result` is probably causing a deadlock

Comment: Yeah that is probably the problem, but the calling method isnt async as its the "public static class MauiProgram" class where the ConfigureLifecycleEvents is being registered

Comment: that's why I suggested using `OnResume`

Comment: So I tried OnResume in the app.cs as updated the main post with the results. basically its the same result

Comment: please be more specific - what exactly is it doing or not doing?  If it is hanging or crashing what line of code does it reach?

Comment: Updated main thread. It hangs at line CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(request)

Comment: Which version are you using?  The plugin has not been updated in over a year.  Have you looked at their open issues?

Comment: Latest beta, Ill take a look

Comment: https://github.com/FreakyAli/Plugin.Maui.Biometric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new .net 6.0 maui project to test your code and it worked when I put the code in the **MainActivity's OnResume method**.

Add permission in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
```

And my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(() => this);
      //bool a = ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.UseBiometric) == Permission.Granted;
      // check the permission at runtime
    }
    protected override async void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        var isAvailable = await CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailableAsync(true);
        if (isAvailable)
        {
            var request = new AuthenticationRequestConfiguration
            ("Login using biometrics", "Confirm login with your biometrics");
            request.AllowAlternativeAuthentication = true;
            var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(request);
            Console.Write(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And the result image:

[image]

Comment: I came back to look at this and it now works. Must have been a reboot that fixed it for me